# Jetpack Compose Paging3 invoke append to load next page

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3

How do I invoke to load the next page to append my database when I reached the last item on

```
val lazyPagingItems = viewModel.getAllItems().collectAsLazyPagingItems()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic loading of more items when you reach the end of the list is part of paging. Here's an article you can read that will show you the steps:

[List view with Pagination using Jetpack Compose](https://medium.com/simform-engineering/list-view-with-pagination-using-jetpack-compose-e131174eac8e)

Comment: can I make the Paging3 load more items only when I've reached the end of the list? or does it do that automatically?

Comment: It automatically loads more items BEFORE you reach the end of the list or the top of the list (when scrolling up).

Answer (score 2):

As @Johann already mentioned in his answer, the mechanism to load more pages are present in the Paging library. If you consider at some point in time trying using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), then for sure the following article will help:

- [How to implement pagination in Firestore using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-76b4c0b5acd5)

And here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestorePaginationJetpackCompose).